# Switch databases in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, database-connection, codeigniter-2

Sorry if this is a real newbie question (also a php newbie), but I can't figure it out from the docs:

I want to be able to use a default database, if I don't speficy anything else, and that works fine using $this->db with the following configuration:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = 'root';
$db['default']['database'] = 'ion_auth';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;

$db['visitorsDB']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['visitorsDB']['username'] = 'root';
$db['visitorsDB']['password'] = 'root';
$db['visitorsDB']['database'] = 'visitorsDB';
$db['visitorsDB']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['visitorsDB']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['visitorsDB']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['visitorsDB']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['visitorsDB']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['visitorsDB']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['visitorsDB']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['visitorsDB']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['visitorsDB']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['visitorsDB']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['visitorsDB']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

But then I want to use the second database in one of my models, so I tried this:

```
function __contruct() {
      parent::__construct();
       $this->db =  $this->load->database('visitorsDB', TRUE);
   }

   public function getAllVisitors($paramArr) {
       //$this->db =  $this->load->database('visitorsDB', TRUE);
```

But that doesn't work. Only if I uncomment the last line so that I load the database in the method itself will it work. I don't understand why. I also tried declaring a new class variable at the beginning of the class - private $myDB; - and then instantiating it in the constructor - $myDB = $this->load->database('visitorsDB', TRUE);

But that didn't work either. So how can I switch database for the entire model?

Comment: When you created a new property in your model (`private $myDB`) and tried to set it from your constructor did you do `$myDB = ...` or `$this->myDB = ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend selecting a second database by overwriting `$this->db`.  Just add a property for your other database in the model you need it and access it through that.  In your model do this:

```
private $myDB;

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->myDB = $this->load->database('visitorsDB', TRUE);
}

function getAllVisitors() {
    return $this->myDB->someMethod(); // Or use active record, etc...
}
```

I know in your question you said that you did something similar but I'm not sure if you did it correctly.  This would be the correct way of doing so and I don't see why it wouldn't work if it was done this way.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but that's exacly how I tried it. I even tried it again now, copying your code, just in case I had made some small mistake, but no go... It just doesn't work. As soon as I put the load statement inside the function though, it works fine. It's as if the function doesn't have access to the database if it is loaded in the constructor, even though I have declared a member variable, and try to access it using $this, just as in your example...

Comment: Actually, the problem was a simple typo... contruct instead of construct in the constructor... So even though I sort of had already tried this, your answer didn't have the typo so I'll credit your answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

when login user with database changed

```
private $db;

function __construct() {
  parent::__construct();

  if($this->session->userdata('username') == "swaroop")
        $this->db = $this->load->database('visitorsDB', TRUE);
    else
        $this->db = $this->load->database('default', TRUE);
}
```